# Matching with time and picking up different values from the dataset

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset like this (whole January, 2016). Analysis time is going every three hours and it creates values for 54 hours ahead.

```
new_data_frame <-
analysis_time       forecast_time       value
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00 26918.20
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 01:00:00 28769.50
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 02:00:00 46015.40
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 45705.50
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 23097.60
..lot of values..
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 04:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 05:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 07:00:00 50000.00
..lot of values..
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00 14594.500
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 07:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 08:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 09:00:00 50000.00
......

> dput(head(new_data_frame))
structure(list(station_id = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), analysis_time = structure(c(1451606400, 
1451606400, 1451606400, 1451606400, 1451606400, 1451606400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), forecast_time = structure(c(1451606400, 
1451610000, 1451613600, 1451617200, 1451620800, 1451624400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), model_id = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), parameter_id = c(407L, 407L, 407L, 407L, 407L, 407L), value = c(26918.2, 
28769.5, 46015.4, 50000, 45705.5, 23097.6)), .Names = c("station_id", 
"analysis_time", "forecast_time", "model_id", "parameter_id", 
"value"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Because some values are missing from the dataset I have to make a time vector (in order to mark missing values as NA) which goes from 2016-01-01 to 2016-02-01.

```
table <-
analysis_time
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 03:00:00
2016-01-01 03:00:00
2016-01-01 03:00:00
2016-01-01 06:00:00
2016-01-01 06:00:00
2016-01-01 06:00:00
2016-01-01 09:00:00
2016-01-01 09:00:00
2016-01-01 09:00:00
.....
```

Then I would always like to pick up first three values beginning from the new analysis time.

So it would look like this:

```
analysis_time       forecast_time       value
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00 26918.20
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 01:00:00 28769.50
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 02:00:00 46015.40
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 04:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 05:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00 14594.500
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 07:00:00 50000.00
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 08:00:00 50000.00
```

My code now looks like this:

```
table[,3] <- new_data_frame$value[match(table$analysis_time,new_data_frame$analysis_time)]
```

But it gives me now the same values from the same analysis time which I don't want. How could I pick up always the next value like above?

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00 26918.200
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 01:00:00 26918.200
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 02:00:00 26918.200
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 50000.000
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 04:00:00 50000.000
2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 05:00:00 50000.000
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00 14594.500
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 07:00:00 14594.500
2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 08:00:00 14594.500
```

Comment: You'd better `dput( head( new_data_frame ) )`, otherwise we don't know how your data looks like.

Comment: I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand OP's intention correctly, it is requested to return the first 3 rows of forecasted values which belong to each `analysis_time`.

This can be solved by ordering `new_data_frame` by `analysis_time` and `forecast_time`, grouping by `analysis_time`, and picking the first three rows within each group.

This can be done in base R, `dplyr`, or `data.table` which I do prefer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(new_data_frame)[order(analysis_time, forecast_time)][
  , head(.SD, 3L), by = analysis_time]
```

> ```
>          analysis_time       forecast_time   value
> 1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00 26918.2
> 2: 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 01:00:00 28769.5
> 3: 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 02:00:00 46015.4
> 4: 2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 50000.0
> 5: 2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 04:00:00 50000.0
> 6: 2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 05:00:00 50000.0
> 7: 2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00 14594.5
> 8: 2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 07:00:00 50000.0
> 9: 2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 08:00:00 50000.0
> ```

Now, the OP has mentioned that *some values are missing from the dataset* which needs to be shown.

This can be achieved by joining with a sequence of time stamps covering the whole period:

```
start_time <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01")
library(lubridate)
time_seq <- seq(start_time, start_time + months(1L), by = "3 hours")
result <- setDT(new_data_frame)[order(analysis_time, forecast_time)][
  , head(.SD, 3L), by = analysis_time][
    .(time_seq), on = .(analysis_time = V1)]
head(result, 12L)
```

> ```
>           analysis_time       forecast_time   value
>  1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00 26918.2
>  2: 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 01:00:00 28769.5
>  3: 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 02:00:00 46015.4
>  4: 2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 03:00:00 50000.0
>  5: 2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 04:00:00 50000.0
>  6: 2016-01-01 03:00:00 2016-01-01 05:00:00 50000.0
>  7: 2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00 14594.5
>  8: 2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 07:00:00 50000.0
>  9: 2016-01-01 06:00:00 2016-01-01 08:00:00 50000.0
> 10: 2016-01-01 09:00:00                <NA>      NA
> 11: 2016-01-01 12:00:00                <NA>      NA
> 12: 2016-01-01 15:00:00                <NA>      NA
> ```

Analysis times which do not appear in `new_data_frame` are now indicated by a single `NA` row.